# Flutter background color

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to change background color on click, and add some text in the middle of the screen, but i can't figure out what is the best way to place this text, i did this:
`

```
main() => runApp(
  const Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    child: MyApp(),
  ),
);

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
Color color =
  Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  color: color,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setState(
        () {
          color = Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
              .withOpacity(1.0);
        },
      );
    },
    child: const Center(child: Text('tttt')),
  ),
);
}
}`
```

and it changes the bg without this line `child: const Center(child: Text('tttt'))`,
but with it it just stops working, so what can i do to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you're wrapping your text with the gesture detector, thus, It'll change the background color when you click on the TEXT.

To solve this, just wrap your entire `Container` with the `GestureDetector`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setState(
        () {
          color = Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
              .withOpacity(1.0);
        },
      );
    },
    child: Container(color:color,child:child),
  ),
);
}
}`
```

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you to use a Scaffold instead of a Container for your body. It'll be easier for you to manage the UI.

Comment: Happy Coding! :)